# spring3mvcportlet populate JSON dojo select

Tags: json, spring, dojo, portlet, populate

I am new to Spring mvc3 portlet and dojo. I am trying to populate select dropdown with JSON data when jsp is loaded. I want to use dojo and give ajax call to controller and return JSON  when jsp is loaded. Any tips will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/yourController")
public class YourController
{
  @RequestMapping(value="/combo/{id}", method=ReqestNethod.GET)
  public String getDropDownData(@ParamValue("id") long id)
  {
    List<Combo> combos = commonDao.getCombos(id);
    String json = JsonUtil.toJson(combos); // or whichever way you use
    return json;
  }
}
```

Send requests from dojo to this url

```
<your-context-path>/yourController/combo/1
```

where 1 is your combo id.

I haven't checked the syntax here.. Wrote it blind. You might get compilation errors.

Comment: Hi Varun  I get data in below format How do I populate dojoType="xwt.widget.form.FilteringSelect" {"ValuesDTO": {"items": [{},{"default": {"size": 5},"int": 10,"string": "Product1","string": "Product1 ","string": "product3","string": "product4","string": "product5"}]}}

I am sending dat in bean--->DTO--->List

Answer (score 0):

I get data in below format 
How do I populate dojoType="xwt.widget.form.FilteringSelect"
{"ValuesDTO": {"items": [{},{"default": {"size": 5},"int": 10,"string": "Product1","string": "Product1 ","string": "product3","string": "product4","string": "product5"}]}}

I am sending dat in bean--->DTO--->List