# s:select to be populated with ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, struts2, dojo

the below response is coming with object response from Struts2 and i have to populate them in s:select tag list.

```
   {"items":[{"label":"BAD CIRCUIT/POOR CONNECTION","key":1100009028300},{"label":"CRACK","key":1100009028340},{"label":"HIGH PRESSURE","key":1100009028260},{"label":"HIGH TEMPERATURE","key":1100009028380},{"label":"LACK OF POWER/NO DRIVE","key":1100009028280},{"label":"LEAKED","key":1100009028220},{"label":"LOOSE","key":1100009028320},{"label":"LOW PRESSURE","key":1100009028240},{"label":"MISSING OR INCOMPLETE","key":1100009028600},{"label":"PITTED/ERODED","key":1100009028360}],"identifier":"key"}

 <s:select id="faultFound"
                    list="#{}" name="faultFoundName" listKey="key" listValue = "label"  emptyOption="true"
                     value="%{destination.key.toString()}"
                     />
```

this is the similar question to me. But i need to put the list in s:select by dojo.
[spring3mvcportlet populate JSON dojo select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781112/spring3mvcportlet-populate-json-dojo-select)

Comment: What do you mean by _onchange ajax_?

Comment: onchange of autocompleter i fired an ajax request.

Comment: Show the code because I don't understand what are you talking.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer Updated:**

In your jsp file you can use `jquery` to populate combo box.

**Code Updated:**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
<s:select id="faultFound" list="#{}" name="faultFoundName"   
   listKey="key" listValue = "label"  emptyOption="true" 
    />
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    loadFaultDropDown();
    });

function loadFaultDropDown() {

        $.getJSON("getFaultsJsonURL", function(j) {
            var options = '<option value="' + "--Select--" + '">'
                    + "--Select--" + '</option>';

            for ( var i = 0; i < j.items.length; i++) {
                //alert(j.items[i].key);
                options += '<option value="' + j.items[i].key + '">'
                        + j.items[i].label + '</option>';
            }
            $("select#faultFound").html(options);

        });
    }
  </script>
```

**Note:**

1. `getFaultsJsonURL` is the URL that you have used for your JSON data retrieval.

> {"items":[{"key":"1100009028300","label":"BAD CIRCUIT/POOR CONNECTION"},{"key":"1100009028260","label":"HIGH PRESSURE"},{"key":"1100009028380","label":"HIGH TEMPERATURE"},{"key":"1100009028280","label":"LACK OF POWER/NO DRIVE"},{"key":"1100009028220","label":"LEAKED"},{"key":"1100009028320","label":"LOOSE"},{"key":"1100009028240","label":"LOW PRESSURE"},{"key":"1100009028600","label":"MISSING OR INCOMPLETE"},{"key":"1100009028360","label":"PITTED/ERODED"}]}

**Output:**

[image: output]

Comment: $("select#faultFound").html(options); not working.It is unable to put the data from options to s:select

Comment: It is normal html...not html 5

Comment: no error actually..it is skipping the  $("select#faultFound").html(options) ...I think the issue is that s:select may not work with options.it has list with key value pair as the source.

Comment: You were right. I have **updated answer** with working code with running **output**. Please find it. Just copy paste in your jsp.